# [Vue warn]: Property or method "rackNumber" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with signalR and Vue.js to update data in a view dynamically, without the need to update the site. This is because the information will be displayed on a TV.

However when I want to render the data I get the following error:
Property or method "rackNumber" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

I'm pretty sure the error is due to document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded'), so I'm just looking for an alternate way to write the same code, so that the site content loads first, and then it's waiting of the data that it will receive from the backend.

My code:

```
<template>
  <main class="principal">
    <div class="columns">
        <div  class="column is-one-fifth fixed">RACK: 
          <span class="number-tool" v-if='rackNumber'>{{ rackNumber }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-one-fifth fixed-2">Estado</div>
        <div class="column is-one-fifth fixed-1">BOX:
           <span class="number-tool" v-if='boxNumber'>{{ boxNumber }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

script:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

const signalR = require('@aspnet/signalr');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
  const app = new Vue({
  /* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
    data() {
      return {
        rackNumber: '',
        boxNumber: '',
        connection: '',
        messages: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      submitRack() {
        if (this.rackNumber) {
          // ---------
          //  Call hub methods from client
          // ---------
          this.connection
            .invoke('SendMessage', this.rackNumber);
          this.rackNUmber = '';
        }
      },
      submitBox() {
        if (this.boxNumber) {
          // ---------
          //  Call hub methods from client
          // ---------
          this.connection
            .invoke('SendMessage', this.boxNumber);
          this.boxNumber = '';
        }
      },
    },
    created() {
      // ---------
      // Connect to our hub
      // ---------
      this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:100/#/Rack')
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
      this.connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toSting()),
      );
    },
  });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you wrapping the code in DOMContentLoaded to wait for all your javascript files to download? If you need to wait for that, try using window.addEventListener("load") instead , OR if you just need DOMContentLoaded for signalR then simply put your event listener for that inside the created() hook

Comment: Hi @Ero! I already tried your solution but it didn't work but for any reason I doubt if I implemented it correctly. Would you please give me an example of it? Thank you!